# WooCommerce - header.php is integrated differently on Category page

Tags: php, wordpress, http-headers, woocommerce

I'm having a weird issue with the way my Category page is displayed, elements of the  selector are displayed in the body tag. This is causing an alignment issue with the navigation bar and the logo header.
Strangely enough this issue occurs only on the Category Page (Archive.php) while the same header.php file is loaded in all of the templates (homepage, product page, category page etc).
I've tried to disable all of the plugins but with no success and also reverted to the original archive.php file but the results are the same.

see the following link: http://www.best-foods-for-fat-burning.com/wordpress/?product_cat=%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%A8-%D7%91%D7%A7%D7%A8

Any assistance or guidance is well appreciated.

Regards
Ofer

Comment: Can you give the link of the other page where the issue is not happening, so that i can see the difference. I don't under stand hebrew so i can't understand which are the other pages.

Comment: yeah sure - http://www.best-foods-for-fat-burning.com/wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Though it is very difficult to debug css without having the actual files in hand, but i think that the right padding in current_page_item is causing the problem,

```
nav li.current_page_item {
    padding-right: 13px;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Change this to,

```
nav li.current_page_item {
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
}
```

And let me know. Think it should work.

Comment: No that doesn't do it. I'll try to emphasize an important discovery that I made with this issue. Elements of the <head> tag are being embedded into the <body> tag for an unknown reason ONLY on the Category pages and I believe that is the issue. The problem is that I don't know what's causing this to happen. I tried disabling plugins but that didn't help. Because this site is running on wordpress it doesn't even make sense to me this should be happening because the same header.php is loaded in each template file.

Comment: The issue is not with plugins. It must be bcoz of css. I wrote the above css from what i found in browser developer tool. it worked fine in the browser. it may not match the css in your file. Find the css which is responsible for that item and change it. Seems like there is some kind of padding generated from either your parent theme, or woo commerce style. try the code in the below code and let know what happens

Comment: nav li.current_page_item {
    padding-right: 0px!important;
}

Comment: No change, I also tried to remove all lines related to nav li.current_page_item. I'm not an expert but it doesn't sense to me it's a css issue, why would something like this cause the <head> to be embedded in the middle of the <body> tag?

Comment: Suman.hassan95, how did you see that that change in the css works. In what browser? It had no effect for me.

Comment: in any browser, just open developer tools (e.g firebug in firefox) and select the code inspecter, and hover/click your mouse on the element you want to check. it will show you the css for that element in the right hand pane.

Comment: I know this, I mean the Category Pages aren't configured to the Nav and so why would the nav li.current_page_item obstruct the header on that page. Also, I edited the CSS like you suggested but there was no change.

Comment: Hi. I am still experiencing an issue with the header on the product Category page versus every other page. For example the meta tags are inserted in the <body> tag only in that template and I just cannot gather my head around this issue. any suggestions will be welcomed. http://www.best-foods-for-fat-burning.com/wordpress/?product_cat=%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%A8-%D7%91%D7%A7%D7%A8